# Для чего нужен @data в assembler простыми словами?

Tags: ассемблер

Для чего предназначен @data в assembler простыми словами и где появляется его необходимость?

Answer (score 1):

@data это индификатор сегмента данных (DATASEG), на место которого после сборки установится реальное смещение данного сегмента. Собственно когда появляется - тогда когда надо работать с данными.

Comment: Можно пример? 
Есть скажем такая инструкция:

mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax

При компиляции что именно обычно подставляется?

Comment: самый простой способ скомпилировать com файл, вы увидите что сегмент кода и сегмент данных идут последовательно, данные идут после окончания кода, вот позиция данных в таком уже готовом двоичном коде и будет записана туда т.к. такие регистры в вашем примере 16битные то там будет слово т.е. 2 байтовая позиция.